# Why is the Meissner effect not used for levitation in MagLev trains?

Tags: electromagnetism, levitation

The Meissner effect does not seem to be used as primary source of levitation in MagLev trains, instead, electromagnetic and electrodynamic syspension are mainly used. Why is this? Could it be that the Meissner effect is not strong enough to carry the weight of a full train?

Comment: Would it be strong enough? Yes, it would be, but why waste the strong field that can be had by a superconductor that has a current flowing trough it?

Comment: I'm not completely sure whether I understand you. Are you saying 'You need a superconductor anyway, so why not use it for electrodynamic suspension and have a (relatively cheap) track with passive coils instead of making the whole track magnetic (using either permanent magnets or electromagnets)'?

Comment: You don't need a superconductor, at all, and most Maglev systems don't have one, if I remember correctly, but once you decide to use one, why not use it to create a strong magnetic field of its own? The forces one can get between two magnets are stronger than the forces between one magnet and one ferromagnet or a perfect diamagnet, but the cost is virtually the same. It really doesn't take much to power a superconducting magnet. The expense is almost all in the cooling.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly cost. To achieve exclusion of magnetic flux for suspension requires not only expensive superconducting materials but also refrigeration systems to lower the superconductor temperature.

The other reason is control. Electromagnetic suspension is inherently unstable when used open loop to suspend objects, but by using sensors and feedback controls can be precisely controlled. The Meissner effect, at least between the superconductor and a permanent magnet is inherently stable, but does not in itself provide an 'input' for up-down or side to side control. So electromagnets would be required in addition to the superconductor.